# Things to use in android game dev

Tags: java, android

Ive been programming android for atleast a month and has created an app but not publish yet. My question is what is the best tool parter with eclipse or some 3rd party software to create an android game? No i dont want 3d games. Im more on story base game. I want to create a simple RPG game like final fantasy(*every game addict know this*) that is simple and not confusing. any sugestions on what to use? or how to get started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look up AndEngine

http://www.andengine.org/

- Some [tutorials](http://andengine.wikidot.com/getting-started-with-andengine) to get you started
- The  [Source Code](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine) for AndEngine

Comment: Thanks.. does it have a huge community? you know to ask some answers.. ^_^

Comment: i haven't used cocos2d myself, and the community you are looking for is the one in your address bar right now :-)